# How do you setup Visual Studio for Mac and NUnit

Tags: nunit, visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual Studio for Mac version 8.5.4 (build 12) and I used NuGet to install Nunit package. I can create a Project NUnit but when I attempt to reference my project I want to test I can't choose my project because it says the .Net target framework is incompatible.

When I added the NUnit project it asked me to pick the target framework and only gave me the option of 2.0, 3.0 and 3.1. Even when I change my project down to 3.1 it still says it's incompatible.

How do you setup Visual Studio for Mac and NUnit

Edit: .Net Standard

Edit 2: I was WRONG. I was using .Net Core and .Net standard together and that was the problem. Thank you everyone.

Comment: You're asking about target frameworks, ut you haven't said what framework __you__ are targeting. :-) Please add that as well as the precise names of the packages and versions you have installed.

Comment: It sounds like you created a .NET Core test project whilst your project being tested is .NET Framework. If you created the `Other - .NET - NUnit Library project` that will target the .NET Framework and should be able to reference your other project.

Comment: What's the type of your project (not the NuGet one)? .NET Core or .NET Standard?

Comment: Matt Ward, that worked with creating a library for my project. Thanks for the help. How can I give you credit for this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using .Net Core and .Net Standard when I wanted to use .Net Standard for everything.